# Devise Registration Path Generates Incorrect Routes for Edit Action After Some Tweaks

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, devise

I was trying to rename all the registrations routes provided by Devise, but now I can't update the account info anymore. It renders `registrations#edit` action via GET request with no problems, but the PUT and DELETE requests all goes to the sign_up path somehow.

Here's my current routes file:

```
...

devise_for :users, path: '', path_names: { sign_in: 'login', sign_out: 'logout', sign_up: 'signup' }, controllers: { registrations: "registrations" }, skip: [:registrations]

as :user do
    get '/admin/cancel' => 'registrations#cancel', as: :cancel_user_registration
    post '/signup' => 'registrations#create', as: :user_registration
    get '/signup' => 'registrations#new', as: :new_user_registration
    get '/admin/settings/account' => 'registrations#edit', as: :edit_user_registration
    put '/admin/settings/account' => 'registrations#update', as: :update_user_registration
    delete '/admin/settings/account' => 'registrations#destroy', as: :destroy_user_registration
end
```

Now when I visit "/admin/settings/account", it renders the edit account view as expected. But the "Update" button points to "/signup" with method PUT, and the "Cancel my account" link also points to "/signup" but with method DELETE.

Then I digged into the view for rendering "registrations/edit", and found these

`<%= simple_form_for(resource, as: resource_name, url: registration_path(resource_name), html: { method: :put }) do |f| %> ...`

`... <%= link_to "Cancel my account", registration_path(resource_name), confirm: "Are you sure?", method: :delete %> ...`

So `registration_path(resource_name)` is actually in charge of generating the correct routes for PUT and DELETE. But since I changed the default Devise registrations routes, it can no longer recognize and spit out the correct paths.

Does anyone know how I can fix this? What does `registration_path(resource_name)` actually mean?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should change your form paths to the paths you created. Like this:

```
<%= simple_form_for(resource, as: resource_name, url: update_user_registration_path, html: { method: :put }) do |f| %>

<%= link_to "Cancel my account", destroy_user_registration_path, confirm: "Are you sure?", method: :delete %>
```

When I was writing my answer I tried googling for the source code so I could show you but I couldn't find it. Anyway, `registration_path` receives an argument which is the name of the model you want to create, update or destroy and then returns the appropriate url to make the call. So imagine you have 2 roles or models: User and Admin. Now, using the same code, you can destroy both using that path. `<%= link_to "Cancel my account", registration_path(resource_name), method: :delete %>` returns `/users/cancel` for a user and returns `/admins/cancel` for an admin.

In your routes.rb file, you are defining the names of routes for a certain model, right? That's what you are doing with the line `as :user do`. You are defining the names of routes for a User. So let's continue with an example of cancelling an account. With this:

```
as :user do
  delete 'delete_account' => 'registrations#destroy', as: :destroy_user_registration
end
```

You can use the `destroy_user_registration_path` without passing `resource_name` because devise already knows that this url is related to the User model.

EDIT: Even if you had more than one model, you could change `registration_path(resource_name)` to `update_user_registration_path` in your view. Remember, all these methods do is create a url to which you submit the form, that's all.

The only thing you have to be careful about is editing your routes file.

Comment: Thanks. But what's `registration_path` for anyway? I'm afraid of screwing up something else by changing the form url.

Comment: Thank you very much for the detailed explanation! I included the `as :user do` block after checking this page https://github.com/plataformatec/devise/wiki/How-To:-Change-the-default-sign_in-and-sign_out-routes from Devise Wiki. As you said, `as :user` (an alias to `devise_scope :user`) is for the user model generated by Devise, so I can safely change `registration_path(resource_name)` to `update_user_registration_path` because I only have one resource - the Devise user resource. Correct me if I'm wrong.